# Unable to fetch Orders(which are not deleted) for logged in user

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to fetch orders for logged in User which I was able to do. But now I have to orders for logged in User which are not marked as deleted as well. I am facing issue to fetch these records using spring-data-jpa. Same scenario I want to implement on User End.I am getting below exception -

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-09-02 05:31:03.699 ERROR 220 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adminController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'journeyFoodServiceImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'journeyFoodServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\TiaaUser\Desktop\AWS\journeyfood\target\classes\org\brahmakumaris\journeyfood\service\JourneyFoodServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'journeyFoodOrderRepository' defined in org.brahmakumaris.journeyfood.repository.JourneyFoodOrderRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List org.brahmakumaris.journeyfood.repository.JourneyFoodOrderRepository.findOrderByUserIdAndNotDisabled(long,boolean) but parameter 'Optional[userId]' not found in annotated query 'SELECT j.orderId,j.headCount,j.dateOfDeparture,j.dateOfOrderPlaced,j.mealRetrievalTime,j.achar,
j.bread,j.jam,j.puri,j.thepla,j.roti,j.others from JourneyFoodOrder j INNER JOIN users u on u.userId=?1 WHERE j.isRemoved=:isRemoved'!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List org.brahmakumaris.journeyfood.repository.JourneyFoodOrderRepository.findOrderByUserIdAndNotDisabled(long,boolean) but parameter 'Optional[userId]' not found in annotated query 'SELECT j.orderId,j.headCount,j.dateOfDeparture,j.dateOfOrderPlaced,j.mealRetrievalTime,j.achar,
j.bread,j.jam,j.puri,j.thepla,j.roti,j.others from JourneyFoodOrder j INNER JOIN users u on u.userId=?1 WHERE j.isRemoved=:isRemoved'!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryMethod.assertParameterNamesInAnnotatedQuery(JpaQueryMethod.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryMethod.<init>(JpaQueryMethod.java:139)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.DefaultJpaQueryMethodFactory.build(DefaultJpaQueryMethodFactory.java:44)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:100)

Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [SELECT j.orderId,j.headCount,j.dateOfDeparture,j.dateOfOrderPlaced,j.mealRetrievalTime,j.achar,
j.bread,j.jam,j.puri,j.thepla,j.roti,j.others from org.brahmakumaris.journeyfood.entity.JourneyFoodOrder j INNER JOIN users u on u.userId=:userId WHERE j.isRemoved=:isRemoved]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74)
```

**JourneyFoodOrder.java** Here **isRemoved** is getting used for marking orders as deleted.

```
    @Entity
public class JourneyFoodOrder{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long orderId;
    
    private int headCount;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date dateOfOrderPlaced;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date dateOfDeparture;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a")
    private Date mealRetrievalTime;

    @ManyToOne
    private UserEntity user; 
    
    private int thepla;
    
    private int puri;
    
    private int roti;

    private int achar;
    
    private int jam;
    
    private int bread;
    
    private int others;
    
    private boolean isRemoved;
//Getter setter and constructors
}
```

**UserEntity.java** Here **isDisabled** is used for marking User as disabled and **enabled** field for enabling(User verification via email).

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long userId;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "userId"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "roleId"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
    
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String nameOfCenter;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String nameOfGuide;
    
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 18)
    private String contactNoOfGuide;
    
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 70)
    private String email;
    
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 70)
    private String zone;
    
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 70)
    private String subZone;
    
    @Column(length = 10)
    private Integer pincode;
    
    private Date dateCreated;
    
    private boolean isDisabled;
    
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String password;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
    private boolean enabled;//whether account is verified using email or not
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private List<JourneyFoodOrder> order;
    
    //Getters, setters and constructor
}
```

**JourneyFoodOrderRepository.java**

```
    @Repository
public interface JourneyFoodOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<JourneyFoodOrder, Long>{
    
    @Override
    void delete(JourneyFoodOrder order);

    @Modifying
    @Query("update JourneyFoodOrder j set j.isRemoved =true where j.orderId =:id")
    void updateIsRemoved(@Param("orderId")Long orderId);

    List<JourneyFoodOrder> findByIsRemoved(boolean isRemoved);

    @Modifying
    @Query("SELECT j.orderId,j.headCount,j.dateOfDeparture,j.dateOfOrderPlaced,j.mealRetrievalTime,j.achar,\r\n"
        + "j.bread,j.jam,j.puri,j.thepla,j.roti,j.others from JourneyFoodOrder j INNER JOIN users u on u.userId=:userId WHERE j.isRemoved=:isRemoved")
    List<JourneyFoodOrder> findOrderByUserIdAndNotDisabled(@Param("userId") long userId, @Param("isRemoved") boolean isRemoved);
}
```

Please help me out in resolving this issue.

Comment: The problem is in the code that's calling your repository method. The caller is not sending `userId` properly. Please let us know how you are calling the repo method.

Answer (score 1):

I was using wrong Entity name causing this issue -

```
@Query("SELECT j.orderId,j.headCount,j.dateOfDeparture,j.dateOfOrderPlaced,j.mealRetrievalTime,j.achar,\r\n"
        + "j.bread,j.jam,j.puri,j.thepla,j.roti,j.others from JourneyFoodOrder j INNER JOIN UserEntity u on u.userId=:userId WHERE j.isRemoved=:isRemoved")
List<JourneyFoodOrder> findOrderByUserIdAndNotDisabled(@Param("userId") long userId, @Param("isRemoved") boolean isRemoved);
```

editing users to UserEntity did resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your for `findOrderByUserIdAndNotDisabled` method query, you have set method parameter as this `j.isRemoved=:isRemoved`. It should be change to `j.isRemoved= ?2`.

Here is the corrected Query

```
@Query("SELECT j.orderId,j.headCount,j.dateOfDeparture,j.dateOfOrderPlaced,j.mealRetrievalTime,j.achar,"
            + "j.bread,j.jam,j.puri,j.thepla,j.roti,j.others from JourneyFoodOrder j INNER JOIN users u on u.userId=?1 WHERE j.isRemoved= ?2")
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't worked. It's facing  ==>org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! So there is something else wrong with this code.

Comment: Replace `INNER JOIN users u` by `INNER JOIN j.users u`

Comment: Now getting - Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: users of: org.brahmakumaris.journeyfood.entity.JourneyFoodOrder [SELECT j.orderId,j.headCount,j.dateOfDeparture,j.dateOfOrderPlaced,j.mealRetrievalTime,j.achar,
j.bread,j.jam,j.puri,j.thepla,j.roti,j.others from org.brahmakumaris.journeyfood.entity.JourneyFoodOrder j INNER JOIN j.users u on u.userId=:userId WHERE j.isRemoved=:isRemoved]